# Bash Script to function as wc command

Tags: bash, getopts

I am trying to create a script using `getopts` that would work as `wc`. the problem is that I get stuck when I use two switches together. The script:

```
while getopts l:w:c: choice
do
         case $choice in
               l) wc -l $OPTARG;;
               w) wc -w $OPTARG;;
               c) wc -c $OPTARG;;
               ?) echo wrong option.
         esac
done
```

When I run this script with `./script.sh -l file` it works, but when I use `./script -wl file` it just goes into an infinite loop. Can anyone please explain what's going on and how to fix it?

Answer (score 4):

You're using it incorrectly. As per the [getopts manual](http://www.lehman.cuny.edu/cgi-bin/man-cgi?getopts%201):

> **If a letter is followed by a colon**, the option is expected to have an
>   argument.

And in your example you're not passing argument for `-w` and `-l` options;

Correct usage is:

```
./script -w file1 -l file2
```

Which will process both options correctly.

**Otherwise** to support an option without argument just use it **without colon** like this:

```
while getopts "hl:w:c:" choice
```

Here option `h` will not need an argument but l, w, c will support one.

Comment: He mentions in the question that he wants script.sh to work like wc,
`wc -w file1 -l file2` is the same thing as `wc -w -l file1 file 2`
not `wc -w file1 ; wc -l file2`

Comment: @dougEfresh: Yes that I read but his scripting of getops still needs a fix.

Comment: true that. I actually question why he/she is doing this in the 1st place. Seems a little strange, but I'm not here to question, just answer

Comment: Well thats "He" :). I think I am not able to properly explain the question. so here I wan't to replace "wc" with the "script". I am aware in getops, a colon after a letter will require an argument (which is, in this case is  filename) I can do commands like you have mentioned @anubhava, but I can't use it  like "wc -lcw $filename". when I try to do ./script -lcw $filename, it takes "c" as an argument and generates an error.

I am trying to learn bash so trying some scripts from the book I have got, thats it.

Answer (score 3):

You need to build the options in the case statement and then execute `wc`:

```
# Set WC_OPTS to empty string
WC_OPTS=();
while getopts lwc choice
do
     case $choice in
            l) WC_OPTS+='-l';;
            w) WC_OPTS+='-w';;
            c) WC_OPTS+='-c';;
            ?) echo wrong option.
     esac
done
# Call wc with the options
shift $((OPTIND-1))
wc "${WC_OPTS[@]}" "$@"
```

Comment: I think this is closest to what the poster wanted. Use `"$@"` instead of `$*` though.

Comment: @ruakh I'm curious, can you show an quick example? I'm not too familiar with bash arrays.

Comment: BTW, per your comment to anubhava, this is still somewhat different from `wc`, in that for some reason `wc` allows options to be interleaved with filenames.

Comment: yeah, mostly cause getopts is somewhat weak when it comes to parsing options.
I like the array, seem to be better and looks cleaner

Answer (score 1):

To add to the other comments . . . the version of `wc` that I have handy seems to handle its options like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

options=()
files=()

while (( $# > 0 )) ; do
    if [[ "$1" = --help || "$1" = --version ]] ; then
        wc "$1"   # print help-message or version-message
        exit
    elif [[ "${1:0:1}" = - ]] ; then
        while getopts cmlLw opt ; do
            if [[ "$opt" = '?' ]] ; then
                wc "$1"   # print error-message
                exit
            fi
            options+="$opt"
        done
        shift $((OPTIND-1))
        OPTIND=1
    else
        files+="$1"
        shift
    fi
done

wc "${options[@]}" "${files[@]}"
```

(The above could be refined further, by using a separate variable for each of the five possible options, to highlight the fact that `wc` doesn't care about the order its options appear in, and doesn't care if a given option appears multiple times.)

Answer (score 0):

```
Got a workaround.

#!/bin/bash

if [ $# -lt 2 ]
then

    echo not a proper usage
    exit

fi

file=$2

while getopts wlc choice

do

    case $choice in 

        l) wc -l $file
            ;;
        w) wc -w $file
            ;;
        c) wc -c $file
            ;;
        ?) echo thats not a correct choice

    esac
done

I think I got obsessed with OPTARG, thanks everyone for your kind help
```